# How to install PhysX 5 SDK?

Tags: c++, nvidia, physics, physx, omniverse

I want to build and experiment with latest PhysX demos, like with kaplademo before. So I found PhysX page, clicked Get PhysX 5 in Omniverse, installed Omniverse… And now what? I don’t see any PhysX SDK mentions. Where to find demos and sources for them? How to install PhysX SDK and get access to its .lib and .h files?

Comment: I second this question. I've been looking for this SDK for almost a year now. You'd think NVIDIA would be embarrassed enough at this point to do something to correct this. There are NVidia YouTube videos reporting "PhysX 5.0 is just around the corner", posted 2 years ago. If its not ready, be honest about it. Don't promote random software by misguiding us.